# Total Commander user it without installation on Windows machine

Tags: windows, installation, total-commander

I love Total commander and have a computer at work where I can NOT install ANYTHING.

Is there a portable Total Commander application that I could use on this machine (meaning - able to open and see all folders, files, do actions without actual installation)?

Thanks.

Comment: Copy the TC’s installation folder from your program files to any location of that other machine. At least couple versions ago it worked fine even without being installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official [tc2usb tool](https://www.ghisler.com/usbinst.htm) to create a portable version using an installed instance of Total Commander. It also copies your settings.